# Installing Android Studio in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: openjdk, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio in Ubuntu 12.04 following the directions from here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating.
When I run studio.sh from android-studio/bin/ I get the following error-message:
"OpenJDK 6 is not supported. Please use Oracle Java or newer OpenJDK."

Then I tried to update or install the openjdk using: "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk"
and "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre", but nothing works.

Any help you could provide I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to install a newer version of JDK. See the [instructions](http://askubuntu.com/q/56104/62483).

Comment: Have you tried openjdk-7-jdk? If that doesn't work you could try downloading Oracle Java from www.java.com.

Comment: @juxiliary: yes, I tried that, and did not work. thanks though.

Comment: @Lucio: Thanks for the info, it seems the right way to do that.